# Can't de-structure props from getStaticProps in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am building an app with Next JS and typescript. I am trying to call data from an api with getStaticProps, and then de-structure the returned props. For some reason, I can't get the props to de-structure.

Here is my getStaticProps function.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const projects = await client.fetch(groq`
  *[_type == "project"]{
    name, url, description, image, tools[]->{name,image}
  }`);

  const tools = await client.fetch(groq`*[_type == "techtool"]{
    name, featured, url, image
  }`);

  return {
    props: {
      projects,
      tools,
    },
  };
}
```

I then am trying to pass projects and tools to my page like so.

```
const Home: NextPage = ({projects, tools}) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Nav />
      <Intro />
      <Contact />
      <Sidebar />
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

However, I am getting the following error when I do this.

```
"Property 'projects' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'."
```

```
"Property 'tools' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'."
```

Do I need to somehow apply an interface to the props? What am I doing wrong?

If I log props to the console without de-structuring, it returns the two arrays it should.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(projects)` or `console.log(tools)`  inside `getStaticProps` Can you see the data.?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is logged to the console I think since this is happening at build time on the server. Absolutely nothing in the console.

If I log props within the page, it does return the data I want, just not de-structured.

Comment: Can you try a console log with some text in `getStaticProps` `eg console.log("Projects")`

Comment: Still nothing. Like I said, this is happening on the server.

Here is the documentation for nextJS.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the props:

```
interface IHomeProps {
    projects: whatGoesHere;
    tools: whatGoesHere;
    children?: ReactNode; // import from react if needed
}

const Home: NextPage = ({projects, tools}: IHomeProps) => {
```

Comment: I don't think `NextPage` is needed? I think one of those generics might be the props... Either way it's not necessary right?

Comment: @NickLeylandMedia Note that you could still used `NextPage` and pass `IHomeProps` as a generics to it, i.e. `const Home: NextPage<IHomeProps> = ({projects, tools}) => { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try use pageProps in your page like this:

```
const Home: NextPage = ({ pageProps: {projects, tools} }) => {
  console.log(projects, tools);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Nav />
      <Intro />
      <Contact />
      <Sidebar />
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

This is how you can get the props from getStaticProps in your page.